# Problems with PATH variable as sudo user

Tags: path, sudo

I'm having trouble to understand how the `PATH` variable is affected by `sudo`. I can run the command `activator` as a normal user because I've added the path where this application resides to that user's `.bashrc` file. I can also ensure this is the case with:

```
user@kubuntu:~$echo $PATH
/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/activator-1.3.2
```

When I try to run `sudo activator`, however, I get sudo:

> activator: command not found

I tried to resolve this by adding the path `/opt/activator-1.3.2` to `/etc/environment`, but I still get the same "command not found" error even though `sudo echo $PATH` shows that `/opt/activator-1.3.2` is in the PATH variable. Even more confusing for me is the fact that if I run `sudo su`, then the activator command runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do:

sudo env "PATH=$PATH" godi_console
As a security measure on Debian, /etc/sudoers has the secure_path option set to a safe value.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but this doesn't really help clear my confusion. I would like to know why the PATH variable is not the same under sudo. What does this secure_path option actually mean?