# How do I modify the PATH at bootup in a way that affects everyone?

Tags: linux, bash, java, path, sudo

I installed a JDK in `/opt`, and placed a shell script in `/etc/profile.d/` where I used `export` to modify the PATH variable so I could run Java nicely. Thing is, this only worked for my local account, not `sudo`. If I try to `sudo` the command, it says `sudo: java: command not found`. I've tried putting the `export` commands at the end of `.bashrc` and `rc.local`, but neither option seems to change this behavior. I want to be able to run `sudo java`, so where can I modify the PATH at bootup time in such a way that `sudo` sees it?

Edit: For the record, these are the lines I've added in every place I've attempted:

```sh
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk-16.0.2"
export PATH="$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"
```

Comment: try `/etc/profile`. :)

Comment: This also didn't seem to work. `java` is recognized, not `sudo java` again

Comment: try look this: [arch wiki: Environment_variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Environment_variables#Globally) or `sudo -E` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not everyone, or even anyone=root. **Your problem is ONLY `sudo`** because `sudo` uses its own PATH; it does NOT use the one set in your (calling) shell, or any other shell or shell config (unless you use `sudo -i` which does run the shell of the target-user, default root, with its usual 'login' configuration) because using a user-controllable PATH could allow security to broken, in violation of sudo's entire reason for existence. See

[How to set path for sudo commands](https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands)
[Why does `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"` do anything at all?](https://superuser.com/questions/1551566/why-does-sudo-env-path-path-do-anything-at-all)
[Passing PATH through sudo](https://superuser.com/questions/98686/passing-path-through-sudo)
[Problems with PATH variable as sudo user](https://superuser.com/questions/916119/problems-with-path-variable-as-sudo-user)

Your most direct solution is to use the full pathname of the program you want to run; rather than typing it out you can do

```
sudo $(which java) # or maybe $(type -p java) in bash
```

which searches java in *your* shell's PATH then invokes sudo with the *result*.

Comment: Thank you. Is there truly no way to modify PATH in such a way that `sudo` will also look at the contents? For example, the program `nano` can be run as `sudo nano` just like it can be run as `nano`. How can I make this happen myself?